# VBA name manager array

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code that get user inputs and outputs a '2 by n' array from cell X33. n varies. Hence I set the VBA code to select this:

```
lastCol = Cells(34, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Range("X33"), Cells(34, lastCol)).Select
```

I am attempting to assign the above selected range into an existing Array2 via Name Manager. When I try record macro via name manager, I am forced to use

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Array2")
    .Name = "Array2"
    .RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R33C24:R34C100"
    .Comment = ""
End With
```

I've attempted by changing C100 above to &lastCol , since the last column in the output can be any number, but the recorded code is fixed and would not assign the array to the selected range I want. Is there any way I may change this code so it would directly take the range selected in the top code instead of a fixed value.

I'm still learning VBA basics as I'm mostly attempting manual edits via recording. Thanks and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim lastCol as long

lastCol = Cells(34, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ActiveWorkbook.Names("Array2")
    .Name = "Array2"
    'written directly
    .RefersToR1C1 = "=Sheet1!R33C24:R34C" & lastCol
    'or from the selected cells
    .RefersToR1C1 = selection.address(1, 1, ReferenceStyle:=xlr1c1, external:=true)
    .Comment = ""
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range(Range("X33"), Cells(34, lastCol)).Name = "Array2"
```